# php email html link, but just showing up as html code

Tags: php, html, xhtml, pear

I'm trying to e-mail a html table, that has links within it.  But when I receive the e-mail, it just shows me the html code itself.

I'm using PHP pear to send the email.

I try constructing a string like so

```
$body = "<table>";

$body = $body . "<tr><td><a href='http://google.ca'>Google</a></td></tr>";

$body = $body . "</table>";
```

then e-mailing it, but when I receive the e-mail, it comes like this

```
<table><tr><td><a href='http://google.ca'>Google</a></td></tr></table>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to ensure you are passing HTML to the setHTMLBody() function. If the problem continues, we'll need to see more of your PHP code.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, thank you!

This article solved everything
http://www.phpmaniac.net/wiki/index.php/Pear_Mail

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're setting the Content or MIME-type for HTML email (which means its just being sent in plain text).

Check out this link for a guide on HTML email in PHP: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php

Comment: short answer is to add this to your headers:
"Content-Type: text/html"